Second order Riesz transforms on a space of unbounded functions
I am wondering if anyone knows of a space $\mathbb{L}(\mathbb R^d)$ (other than the $BMO(\mathbb R^d)$ space) that satisfies the following properties:

$\mathbb{L}(\mathbb R^d)$ lies between $L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ and all $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb R^d)$, with $p<\infty$:
$$
     L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)\subsetneq \mathbb{L}(\mathbb R^d)  \subset \bigcap_{p\geq 2}^{\infty} L^p_{loc}(\mathbb R^d).
   $$
Contains discontinuous functions such as:
$$
f=\mathbb 1_{D}.
$$
Stable under (second-order) Riesz transforms?

At least the space of exponentially integrable functions $L^{exp}(\mathbb R^d)$ satisfies 1. and 2. However, I am not sure if it is stable under Riesz transforms. It is defined as follows:
$$
L^{exp}(\mathbb R^d)=\left\{f : \exists \;\lambda>0 \;\;\text{such that}\;\;\int_{\mathbb R^d} \left(e^{\frac{|f(x)|}{\lambda}}-1\right)dx<\infty\right\}.
$$
Are there any Yudovich or Orlicz spaces that possess these properties? I don’t have a strong grasp of harmonic analysis, so any comments are welcome.
Thank you.

I think the first inclusion cannot hold. Unless you are not on the whole Euclidean space.

You are right. I was only considering the torus $\mathbb{T}^d$.  For the entire Euclidean space, it may be $L^p_{loc}$.

A space that is preserved by Riesz transforms, is such that is also imposes the function/distribution to have $0$-mean over the whole Torus. Therefore, it cannot contain any non-essentially $0$ characteristic functions.

I have updated my request, taking your comments into account.
